# guardar foto en 2 tablas distintas base de datos java oracle

Tags: java, oracle, imagen, blob

estoy hace 2 dias tratando de guardar una foto en 2 tablas distintas de una base de datos, lo raro es que en la primera tabla guarda la imagen pero en la segunda no, paso el codigo:

```
@Override
    public void GrabarFoto(InputStream uploadedInputStream, FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws SQLException {



        String detalleArchivo = fileDetail.getFileName();
        String[] partes = detalleArchivo.split("_", 2);             
        String data2 = partes[1];
        String[] parts = data2.split("\\.");
        System.out.println("registro"+ partes[0]+"licencia o dni"+parts[0]);

        String ACMNRO = partes[0];
        String tipoImagen = parts[0];

        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {
            dbConnection = Conexion.obtenerConexion();

            if(tipoImagen.equals(LICENCIA)) {
                stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(
                        "UPDATE ACTACAMINERA SET ACMFOTOLICENCIA=? where ACMNRO=? ");
            }else {
                stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(
                        "UPDATE ACTACAMINERA SET ACMFOTODNI=? where ACMNRO=? ");
            }


            stmt.setBinaryStream(1, uploadedInputStream);
            stmt.setString(2, ACMNRO);
            stmt.executeUpdate();



        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

              try{
                 if(stmt!=null)
                     dbConnection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
              }
              try{
                 if(dbConnection!=null)
                     dbConnection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
                 se.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
        int OJTID= obtenerObjetoId(ACMNRO);
        guardarObjetoDescriptivo(OJTID,uploadedInputStream,tipoImagen);

    }

    private void guardarObjetoDescriptivo(int oJTID, InputStream uploadedInputStream, String tipoImagen) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        try {
            dbConnection = Conexion.obtenerConexion();


            if(tipoImagen.equals(LICENCIA)) {
                stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("UPDATE OBJETO_DATOS_DESCRIPTIVOS SET ODDFOTOLICENCIA=? where OJTID=?");
            }else {
                stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("UPDATE OBJETO_DATOS_DESCRIPTIVOS SET ODDFOTODNI=? where OJTID=?");

            }

            stmt.setBinaryStream(1, uploadedInputStream);
            stmt.setInt(2, oJTID);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("aquiiiiiiiiii"+oJTID);


        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

              try{
                 if(stmt!=null)
                     dbConnection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
              }
              try{
                 if(dbConnection!=null)
                     dbConnection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
                 se.printStackTrace();
              }
           }

    }

    private int obtenerObjetoId(String aCMNRO) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement  stmt =null;
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        int OJTID = 0;

        try {
            dbConnection = Conexion.obtenerConexion();
            stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("select * from OBJETOS where OJTIDENTIFICADOR1= ?");
            stmt.setString(1, aCMNRO);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                OJTID=rs.getInt("OJTID");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
             try{
                 if(stmt!=null)
                     dbConnection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
              }
              try{
                 if(dbConnection!=null)
                     dbConnection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
                 se.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
        return OJTID;
    }
```

El metodo de "grabarFoto" me guarda la imagen perfectamente, luego llamo el metodo "obtenerObjetoId" que me obtiene el id de la tabla el cual tambien me devuelve el id correcto, por ultimo el metodo donde estoy teniendo el problema es en el "guardarObjetoDescriptivo" en donde no me tira ningun tipo de error pero no me guarda la foto en el registro, alguien me podria dar una mano con esto por favor? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Comentas que no te lo guarda pero no te tira error alguno, has probado de debugarlo no vaya a ser que te entre en algun lugar donde no tengas el stacktrace printado o en caso que entre podras leer el stacktrace del error. Eso ayudaría para saber el motivo.

Comment: si hice debug y lo mas raro es que el stmt.executeUpdate(); me devuelve 1, lo que en teoria quiere decir que se ejecuto correctamente

Comment: Entonces nose porque puede ser sin mas información sorry

Comment: no hay drama, yo ya la verdad que no entiendo cual seria el problema